# SQL Exception: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM transaction WHERE user_id='"+user_id+"' AND product_id='"+product_id+"' limit 1");
```

I am getting the error for above statement as the statement is not ended properly. I am using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that you want to delete just one row - **which** row would that be? Any? In that case, use `ROWNUM`, e.g.

```
SQL> delete from test where deptno = 10 and rownum = 1;

1 row deleted.
```

Translate it to code you use; I don't know what it is.

Comment: i have transaction(transaction_id,user_id,product_id)

Comment: OK, that doesn't change what I said. Just include `and rownum = 1` condition.

Comment: actually i am executed it and worked in sql command line but when i do it in netbeans by passing statement its not working

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know "netbeans". Statement - as is - works correctly as far as Oracle is concerned (as you've noticed).

Answer (score 0):

Limit 1 is not the ORACLE syntax. Please remove it and run your query without LIMIT 1.

Comment: but i want to delete just one row